# How to initialize a custom class object in the form of a list in C#

Tags: c#

```
public class EmployeeSyncModel
 {
        public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
        public string DAPName { get; set; }
        public int LocationCode { get; set; }
        public int Status { get; set; }
 }
```

```
List<EmployeeSyncModel> obj = new List<EmployeeSyncModel>();
```

I want to initialize a list object with the above model. Having default values.

For example, as we do :

```
List<string> obj2 = new List<string>() { "abh", "csd" };
```

Comment: Well you can use `List<EmployeeSyncModel> list = new List<EmployeeSyncModel> { new EmployeeSyncModel { EmployeeId = 10, ... } };` It's not really clear to me which part is causing problems for you at the moment.

Comment: What are "default values" for you? You can simply initialize them, then the string property has the default `null` and the integers `0`. If that's not the right _default value_ provide a method `public static EmployeeSyncModel Default` which returns an instance with the right default values. Or pick an answer below which shows how to initialize them individually.

Comment: Note that if any of the object parameters are required for the objects correct functioning, they should probably be constructor parameters. You might also consider making parameters read only, or init only, if possible.

Answer (score 1):

Pretty simple, type :

```cs
List<EmployeeSyncModel> obj2 = new List<EmployeeSyncModel>()
{
    new EmployeeSyncModel()
    {
        EmployeeId = 1,
        DAPName = "name1",
        LocationCode = 2,
        Status = 3,
    },
    new EmployeeSyncModel()
    {
        EmployeeId = 4,
        DAPName = "name2",
        LocationCode = 5,
        Status = 6,
    },
}
```

And then you have an instanciated List with 2 instances inside.

For default values, simply type :

```cs
List<EmployeeSyncModel> obj2 = new List<EmployeeSyncModel>()
{
    new EmployeeSyncModel(),
    new EmployeeSyncModel()
}
```